# Managing SnappyData cluster with YARN

Tags: snappydata

Is it possible to manage SnappyData cluster with YARN.
The requirement is to containerise snappy data cluster, so that it can be managed by YARN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find out more about using YARN with SnappyData here:

http://snappydatainc.github.io/snappydata/programming_guide/working_with_hadoop_yarn_cluster_manager/

In short, when used in Smart Connector mode, YARN can manage Spark.

Also, a Docker image of SnappyData exists here:

http://snappydatainc.github.io/snappydata/quickstart/getting_started_with_docker_image/

And SnappyData-on-Kubernetes is coming out shortly. You can track it here:

https://github.com/SnappyDataInc/spark-on-k8s